# git reset --merge lost local changes

Tags: git, gitlab

after taking pull I got conflicts, so i run git reset --merge
now i lost my local changes how can i get that back.

expecting the solution to get back my local changes that was lost.
git reset --merge
Looking for a solution
after taking pull I got conflicts

Comment: Repeating a question three times does not help in getting answers. Repeating a question three times does not help in getting answers. Repeating a question three times does not help in getting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ran `git reset --merge` without committing or stashing your local changes, they are likely lost since Git doesn't track uncommitted changes after a reset.

But still, there are a few things you could try:

- You can try checking your **IDE/editor's local history** for a record of your changes.
- **Check Git Stashes**: Use `git stash list`to see if you stashed the changes earlier.
- **Reflog**: If the changes were committed at some point, use `git reflog` to find and recover them.
- **File Recovery Tool**: As a last resort, try using a file recovery tool (works only if you saved the changes to the disk and not just in the editor)

In the future, regularly committing or stashing changes can prevent such losses. Unfortunately, if these options don't help, the changes might be irrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Recycle Bin, you might find them there.